# How does Spring Boot automatically include code from dependencies included in the pom file?

Tags: spring-boot, components

For example, when we include `spring-boot-starter-web` in a project it knows to set up and run tomcat without any external prompting. How does spring know how to do that?

I have some common components that I would like to include in multiple projects, and have them start in a similar fashion.

I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot leverages the concept of starters, e.i. dependencies with autoconfiguration classes. Those classed usually have `@ConditionalOn*` annotation with described bean and when application context is starting up Spring scans those classes and decides whether autoconfiguration eligible for bean instantiation. In your case there's `ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration` which in turn imports `ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration.EmbeddedTomcat`:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnClass({ Servlet.class, Tomcat.class, UpgradeProtocol.class })
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = ServletWebServerFactory.class, search = SearchStrategy.CURRENT)
static class EmbeddedTomcat {

    @Bean
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatServletWebServerFactory(
            ObjectProvider<TomcatConnectorCustomizer> connectorCustomizers,
            ObjectProvider<TomcatContextCustomizer> contextCustomizers,
            ObjectProvider<TomcatProtocolHandlerCustomizer<?>> protocolHandlerCustomizers) {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        factory.getTomcatConnectorCustomizers()
                .addAll(connectorCustomizers.orderedStream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
        factory.getTomcatContextCustomizers()
                .addAll(contextCustomizers.orderedStream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
        factory.getTomcatProtocolHandlerCustomizers()
                .addAll(protocolHandlerCustomizers.orderedStream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Here we have `@ConditionalOnClass({ Servlet.class, Tomcat.class, UpgradeProtocol.class })` which means that Tomcat should be started when those classes are present in the classpath.

For deeper understanding of starter concept see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starters